# Using placeholder as the typical id attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This question will probably either be extremely someone or flat out impossible. Inside of JavaScript how would I go about changing the value attribute of a input tag in html based on the placeholder value? 
This question does sound dumb as a normal person would just set each of the divisions with different ids and change it that way. However, I’m creating an extension for a page with JavaScript that doesn’t have id values on the input tags. 
Note: all of the placeholder texts are different, there are pretty much no id parent divisions except the wrapper, all the classes are the same for the input tag I wish to modify.

Thanks in advance. (It’s a dumb question I know. Forgive me)

Html I’m editing

```
<input type=“tel” maxlength=“1” placeholder=“1” value class=“UIInput-input>
```

It’s the same thing for the rest but each time the place holder goes up by one.

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: @DanielD added. Thanks for reminding me

Comment: have you tried `document.querySelector('input[placeholder="whatever"]')`

Comment: You can't use "smart quotes" in HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find elements in the DOM based on attributes other than ID or Class, you can use the `document.querySelector()` method.

In your particular example, you would use it like this:

```
var newValue = 'my new value for my input element';
document.querySelector('input[placeholder="1"]').value = newValue;
```